# Hide object in a specific area

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, properties

I have two 3D VIEW areas, and I would like to hide an object only from one of these.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but requires the sphere to be in a separate collection. Assuming it is, you can use the following steps to hide it in one area, while still displaying the object in the other.

1. Open the sidebar by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> and select the *View* tab in it.
2. Expand the panel named *Collections*
3. Enable *Local Collections*, this allows you to have different (local) visibility settings per 3D view area.
4. Hide the collection with the sphere by clicking on the eye icon behind its collection in the panel

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your time